# Starting task in the button click handler causes aggregate exception

Tags: c#, exception, task, aggregate

please help someone.
I want to create and start a new task in the button click handler and it always causes aggregate exception. I'm doing the following:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<Image> t  = Task<Image>.Factory.StartNew(InvertImage,
                        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    t.ContinueWith( task => { 
                             some code here;
                             pictureBox1.Image = t.Result; 
                            },
                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletition);

    t.ContinueWith( task => { some code here },
                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
 }

 private Image InvertImage()
 { some code here }
```

The code if run in the main thread works perfectly, so here is definetely something wrong with my understanding of using Tasks. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Winforms(or even in WPF) only the  thread who create  the component can update it you should make your code thread-safe.
For this reason the debugger raises an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." which is encapsulated as AggregateException because tasks encapsulate all exceptions  in aggregate exception

you can use this code to iterate through all exceptions  in aggregate exception  raised by the task

```
try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // Assume we know what's going on with this particular exception. 
    // Rethrow anything else. AggregateException.Handle provides 
    // another way to express this. See later example. 
    foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (e is MyCustomException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

To make  your thread safe just do something like this

```
// If the calling thread is different from the thread that
// created the pictureBox control, this method creates a
// SetImageCallback and calls itself asynchronously using the
// Invoke method.


 // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting
    // the text property on a TextBox control.
    delegate void SetPictureBoxCallback(Image image);  

// If the calling thread is the same as the thread that created
// the PictureBox control, the Image property is set directly. 

private void SetPictureBox(Image image)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.picturebox1.InvokeRequired)
    {    
        SetPictureBoxCallback d = new SetPictureBoxCallback(SetPictureBox);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { image });
    }
    else
    {
        picturebox1.Image= image; 
    }
}
```

Comment: t.ContinueWith generate  a new task which may be or not the some thread so  your pictureBox1.Image should not be there  it should be invoked  on  UI thread as I have explained and you  do the task.Wait for all tasks even for t.continueWith

Answer (score 2):

By default continuation runs on default scheduler which is Threadpool Scheduler. Threadpool threads are always background threads so they can't update the UI components (as UI components always run on foreground thread). So your code won't work.

**Fix: Get the scheduler from UI thread.This will ensure that the continuation runs on the same thread which created the UI component**

```
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

and than pass it to ContinueWith function.

```
t.ContinueWith( task => { 
                             some code here;
                             pictureBox1.Image = t.Result; 
                            },
                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletition,scheduler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use a Task result within the calling thread is using `async/await` key word. This way compiler do the work of capture the right `TaskScheduler` for you. Look code below. You need to add `try/catch` statements for Exceptions handling.

This way, code is still asynchronous but looks like a synchronous one, remember that a code should be readable.

```
      var _image = await Task<Image>.Factory.StartNew(InvertImage, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

      pictureBox1.Image = _image;
```